# Deploy a Java Enterprise Application fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jboss

Using Netbeans, I've created my Java Enterprise Application with a ejb module and a war module.
I've done some changes in the war module and everything worked just fine. But now I'm trying to call an remote ejb defined in the ejb module. I've followed this tutorial https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html.
Now, when I try to deploy the ear file in my applicational server (JBoss AS7) I get the following error:

> {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps
>   that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services"
>   => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"events.ear\".\"events-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE"
>   => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"events.ear\".\"events-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE:
>   Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment
>   \"events-ejb.jar\" of deployment \"events.ear\""}}}}
>   /Users/Luis/NetBeansProjects/events/nbproject/build-impl.xml:307: The
>   module has not been deployed.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

**teste-ejb module**
**NewSessionBean**

```
package a;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class NewSessionBean implements NewSessionBeanRemote {

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")
}
```

**teste-war module** (not modified)

**AuthenticationInterface** (the java application)
**SessionbeanRemote**

```
package a;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface NewSessionBeanRemote {

}
```

**2º EDIT**

> 17:59:24,759 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed
>   to define class a.NewSessionBean in Module
>   "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link a/NewSessionBean (Module
>   "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
>           at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
>           at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:63)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
>   [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/NewSessionBeanRemote
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
>           ... 19 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.NewSessionBeanRemote from [Module "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main"
>   from Service Module Loader]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>           ... 24 more
>
> 17:59:24,860 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-4) Failed
>   to define class a.NewSessionBean in Module
>   "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link a/NewSessionBean (Module
>   "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:225)
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/NewSessionBeanRemote
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.NewSessionBeanRemote from [Module "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main"
>   from Service Module Loader]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at 
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
>
> 17:59:24,970 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."teste-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."teste-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment "teste-ejb.jar"
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>           at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>   [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51] Caused by:
>   org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:
>   Could not load EJB class a.NewSessionBean
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:227)
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.deploy(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:97)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
>   [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>           ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.NewSessionBean from [Module "deployment.teste-ejb.jar:main" from
>   Service Module Loader]
>           at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
>           at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>           at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.getEjbClass(BusinessViewAnnotationProcessor.java:225)
>           ... 7 more
>
> 17:59:25,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads -
>   1) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "teste-ejb.jar" was rolled back
>   with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"teste-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"teste-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"teste-ejb.jar\""}} 17:59:25,037 INFO
>   [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877:
>   Stopped deployment teste-ejb.jar in 3ms 17:59:25,059 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774:
>   Service status report JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:
>   service jboss.deployment.unit."teste-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."teste-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment "teste-ejb.jar"
>
> 17:59:25,071 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation
>   failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
>   => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"teste-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" =>
>   "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit.\"teste-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process
>   phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"teste-ejb.jar\""}}}}

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any other errors in your log?  Can you share the whole thing?

Comment: I create a new project to and I made just like in the tutorial and it seems to work. I'm remaking my hole project now to find the error. If the error persists, I'll post the code. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well, it seems it's still not working... Can you tell me what are the right steps to create a remote ejb in Netbeans, using an enterprise application?

Comment: I still need the relevant errors from your log file.

Comment: The only think I do is the following: 1- create a enterprise application with an ejb and a web module. 2- create a java application without main. 3- create a remote session bean using the java application above. I only need to do this so that I can't deploy the ejb module. I'll updat emy post with the code I get after doing this.

Comment: I don't think I need code...  can you please share the logfile so I can see the errors?

Comment: I uploaded the log file

Comment: This: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: a/NewSessionBeanRemote` is the problem.  How are you deploying?

Comment: I just press in the project and choose run

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about netbeans.  I would suggest using GlassFish like the tutorial you linked above.  If you really want to use JBoss AS 7 then you need to start reading documentation.  By default, modules in JBoss can't see eachother due to proper isolated classloaders.  My guess is you just need to either turn that off or package your code properly.  Documentation here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide